# Should I find my advisor for letter of recommendation if I obtained a low grade in thesis?

Tags: recommendation-letter, interpersonal-issues

I am a master student in Germany. My thesis obtain 3.0 in German grade, which is a low grade I think. My original plan is to find my advisor to write the letter of recommendation for my application to PhD. But will my advisor recommend me, or write something bad in the letter? Should I find my advisor for the letter?

Comment: We cannot know what your advisor might write in such a letter, only they themselves can. Why not talk to them about it?

Answer (score 1):

In most subjects, a 3.0 is a very low grade. Admitting someone with a 3.0 in their MSc dissertation to a PhD is something I'd only consider in rare circumstances (I'm doing PhD admissions in CS at a UK university). The expected way for me to learn about these special circumstances is through the reference letters.

Thus, most likely it doesn't matter anyway. If your bad performance in the dissertation was due to matters beyond your control, a well-crafted letter by your advisor might give you a chance. If the problem was in the person of your advisor, you'd need a well-established academic who knows your advisor well-enough (but doesnt like them) to explain this.

Comment: In your understanding, what is the 3.0 out of?

Comment: @YemonChoi It's not really "out of" anything. The grades in Germany range from a 4 (barely passing) to a 1 (excellent). Individual grades often can take also .3 and .7 intermediate values. Final grades are weighted averages of the individual grades, hence anything in 0.1 increments between 4.0 and 1.0 is possible.